Optional Binding Parameters
I have a view that takes an optional binding boolean variable. I'd like to pass a variable to it from certain views only. The problem I'm having is when I pass a variable, I get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool?>'", and when I don't, I get the error "Missing argument for parameter 'toggle' in call". Below Is the code I have. Thank you.
Heading(text: "Heading1") // error: Missing argument for parameter 'toggle' in call

Heading(text: "Heading2", toggle: $booleanVar) // Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Bool>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool?>'

struct Heading: View {
    @State var text: String
    @Binding var toggle: Bool?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 25)
            
            HStack {
                Text(text)
                    .font(.system(size: 36))
                
                Spacer()
                
                if text == "str" {
                    Button(action: { toggle!.toggle() }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .font(.system(size: 36))
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 25)
            
        }
    }
}


One solution is to change the property to non-optional and just call the view as Heading(text: "Heading1", toggle: .constant(false)) when you don't want to use it but the whole design just feels wrong and I think that you should solve this without using @Binding like this.

What is the sense of an optional Bool if you force unwrap the optional anyway? By definition a Bool has two states. If you need more use a custom enum.

It seems like you want a Binding<Bool>?, not a Binding<Bool?>. The former cannot be declared as a property wrapper.
You should declare it as a regular let property:
struct Heading: View {
    // text should not be a @State either!
    let text: String
    let toggleBinding: Binding<Bool>?

From the code in body, it seems like you expect the caller to pass in a a non-nil binding when text is "str". In that case, I would enforce this by writing two initialisers:
init(toggle: Binding<Bool>) {
    self.text = "str"
    self.toggleBinding = toggle
}

init(text: String) {
    self.text = text
    self.toggleBinding = nil
}

Instead of force-unwrapping the binding, you should unwrap it safely like any other optional:
if let toggleBinding {
    Button(action: { toggleBinding.wrappedValue.toggle() }) {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .font(.system(size: 36))
    }
}

Note that you have to toggle() the toggleBinding.wrappedValue, instead of just toggleBinding.
